# Multiple variable in propel create-query

Tags: php, mysql, propel

According to the `api` (http://trac.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/ModelCriteria) I was searching for something like that:

```
$param1 = 5;
$param2 = 3;

select id, name from testtable where ((sin(?) * (cos(?));
```

equal to

```
select id, name from testtable where ((sin($param1) * (cos($param2));
```

How can I do this with propel? I only found a way to bind only 1 variable at once.

(I don't want to do a "AND" I just want to bind **more** than 1 variable)

From the docs, this is for binding **one** variable:

```
<?php
// Finding all Books where title = 'War And Peace'
$books = BookQuery::create()
  ->where('Book.Title = ?', 'War And Peace')
  ->find();
?>
```

Comment: In your query, part `(sin(?) * (cos(?)` is not logic (true/false) evaluation for where syntax???

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess Propel works like Doctrine for this point, did you try :

```
$res = TestQuery::create()
  ->where('((sin(?) * (cos(?))', array($param1, $param2))
  ->find();
```

Ps: the link for documentation is so old, use the new one: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html

Comment: Hi j0k, I tried it, but it failed. (Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause)
I couldn't also found soemthing in the api doc about binding two params..

Comment: In fact, the error says that you need to give a column to the where clause. Can't you give a column in the where clause?

Comment: I have no idea how this should work...

this is my where clause: $farmers->where('ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(?))*SIN(RADIANS(latitude))+COS(RADIANS(?))*COS(RADIANS(latitude))*COS(RADIANS(longitude-?)))*6371 > ?', array($curLat, $curLat, $curLon, $settingsArea));